# Game slower when objects are seen pygame

Tags: python, pygame

I'm making a Flappy Bird game, and every time the bird is alone and no pipes are in the frame the game goes much faster, I tried with lower screen resolution, and it's still the same. when the bird is moving between pipes the game is normal speed and slows down right after.

**sizes:
background - 700x1000,
bird - 100x56,
pipe - 150x525,
pipe_reversed - 150x525**

```
import pygame
import random 
pygame.init()

win = pygame.display.set_mode((700, 1000))
pygame.display.set_caption("Flappy Bird")


pipe_x = 1000
pipe_y = 500
movement = 0


x = 200
y = 500
gravity = 3
rotation = 30
rv_pipe = pygame.image.load(r'pipe_reversed.png')
pipe = pygame.image.load(r'pipe.png')
bg = pygame.image.load(r'background.jpg')
bird = pygame.image.load(r'bird.png')
icon = pygame.image.load(r'icon.jpg')

pygame.display.set_icon(icon)



while True:
    win.blit(bg, (0,0))
    pygame.time.delay(1)
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit() 
        keys = pygame.key.get_pressed() 

        if keys[pygame.K_ESCAPE]:
               pygame.quit() 

        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
               gravity -= 10
               if rotation > 70:
                   rotation = 45
               
    #gravity
    gravity += 0.1
    y += gravity
    if gravity >= 4:
        gravity = 4
    if gravity <= -3:
        gravity = -3
    
    #rotation  
    if rotation >= 20:
        rotation = 20
    if rotation <= -90:
        rotation = -90
    if gravity < 0: 
        rotation += 2
    if gravity > 1: 
        rotation -= 0.5
    
    #pipe 
    pipe_x -= 1
    if pipe_x == -150:
        pipe_x = 700
    


    bird2 = pygame.transform.rotate(bird, rotation)
    print (gravity)

    win.blit(pipe, (pipe_x, pipe_y))    
    win.blit(rv_pipe, (pipe_x, pipe_y - 700))
    win.blit(bird2, (x, y))
    pygame.display.update()
```

Answer (score 0):

better You set a clock tick rate to fix this problem

Comment: This is more of a comment than an answer.